# How to add newLine in xslt mapping

Tags: xml, xslt

How to add newline or line break in the xslt mapping code?

I have xml code like this:

`<CData>AcctEntryId,ValueDate,Entity 1,2018-02-21,XYZ 2,2018-03-22,ABC<CData>`

I want data to look like this:

`AcctEntryId,ValueDate,Entity
 1,2018-02-21,XYZ
 2,2018-03-22,ABC`

Comment: Please show us your existing "xslt mapping code" and make sure we understand if you are using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: If your delimiter is always ` ` (space) then `translate()` function will fine in all version of XSLT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use simply `translate()` function its easily provide you the desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="CData">
        <xsl:for-each select="translate(., ' ', '&#x000a;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see the link for reference: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbL

Comment: Hi Amrendra, all of line records are separated using LF (&#x000a) ,so while converting this xml , I wish to insert line break or new line instead of LF (&#x000a).. Can you please let me know what changes are needed to be done? So each line of records will be on new line

Comment: If i use the above code, every code having space in between them are getting post on new line

Comment: @Kaushik If you have values containing spaces, then what is your record separator?

Comment: Hi Michael, the field separator is ','(comma) and record separator is 'nl'(new line) (LF)

Comment: @Kaushik That makes no sense. I am asking about your input. The example you have posted suggests that space is used as the record separator. If there are also in-field spaces, then this is an impossible task.

Comment: P.S. It makes no sense to use `xsl:for-each` on the result of `translate()`. There will be only one. @Amrendra Kumar